# Instantiate an Empty SearchResultCollection

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need a way to instantiate an empty SearchResultCollection so that callers are guaranteed a valid SearchResultCollection, regardless of any Exceptions processed in a method.

I am not looking to Mock anything up as answered here: [Moq C# built in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906637/moq-c-sharp-built-in-class)

I have a class that does various AD searches using either the DirectorySearcher.FindOne or DirectorySearcher.FindAll methods.

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchroot, filter);

try{
    return searcher.FindAll();
} catch {
    return new SearchResultCollection(); //No constructor that I find.   
}
```

By a design decision, I expect each method should return a valid (possibly empty) SearchResultCollection even if AD throws an exception.  This is so callers may use a foreach loop to process and not be concerned with any null return objects from the method.  In other words, the return should either be a collection valid return records or an empty collection in the same format.

My alternative is to use a List which works, but adds complexity without much value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also could not find a constructor for a SearchResultCollection however if the search fails, you might try a default in the catch that will return the collection with 0 entries.

```
        DirectorySearcher searcher;
        SearchResultCollection ret;

        try
        {
            //Unknown search request
            searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchroot, filter);
            ret = searcher.FindAll();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Default known that will return a collection with 0 entries
            searcher = new DirectorySearcher(null, "");
            ret = searcher.FindAll();
        }

        return ret;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  That almost worked, and I'm marking as the answer with the only change being that: searcher=new DirectorySearcher(null, "") actually returned from the method, but failed with "bad filter" when enumerating in the foreach.  No big problem, I used a filter that would always be false (2=4) and that effectively returns an empty set.  More testing, but looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't. You may somehow capture an empty `SearchResultCollection`, keep a static reference to it and use it as a fallback value in your api but it's completely wierd since that collection implements `IDisposable` and it should be disposed eventually.

If you don't like to return an empty list, you can try to create extension methods like `EmptyIfNull()`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> me)
{
    return me ?? new List<T>();
}

DirectoryHelper.FindAll().EmptyIfNull().foreach
```